Laravel orchid column group with component
how can i make table column with group that has component?
TD::make('status', __('Payment status'))
  ->render(fn (BillPayment $model) => Group::make([
    Layout::component(BillPaymentStatusComponent::class),
    Button::make(__('Confirm payment'))
      ->method('confirmPayment', [
        'model' => $model
      ])
      ->canSee($model->status == 'pending')
  ])),

And when I try it, I get an error :
Object of class Orchid\Screen\Layouts\Component@anonymous could not be converted to string

